# Rails 5.0 devise default sign up not taking/saving custom attribute input in DB

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise

The sign up file

Sign up

```
<%= form_for(resource, as: resource_name, url: registration_path(resource_name)) do |f| %>
  <%= devise_error_messages! %>
<div align="center">
  <div class="field" >
    <%= f.label :email %><br />
    <%= f.email_field :email, autofocus: true %>
  </div>

  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :password %>
    <% if @minimum_password_length %>
    <em>(<%= @minimum_password_length %> chara min)</em>
    <% end %><br />
    <%= f.password_field :password, autocomplete: "off" %>
  </div>

  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :password_confirmation %><br />
    <%= f.password_field :password_confirmation, autocomplete: "off" %>
  </div>

   <div class="field" >
    <%= f.label :designation %><br />
    <%= f.text_field :designation, autofocus: true %>
  </div>

  <div class="actions">
    <%= f.submit "Sign up" %>
  </div>
  <%= render "users/shared/links" %>
</div>
<% end %>
```

---

---

The RegistrationsController
private

```
def sign_up_params
    params.require(:designation).(:email, :password)

end
```

---

---

The ERROR
ActionController::ParameterMissing (param is missing or the value is empty: designation):

=======
Just have to take value in the designation attribute but it is always nil

Comment: check it out https://github.com/plataformatec/devise#strong-parameters

Comment: It worked, Thanks you !!!

Answer (score 0):

Please check below code

```
<%=form_for(resource,as:resource_name,url:registration_path(resource_name)) do |f| %> 

 <%= devise_error_messages! %> 
  <div align="center">
     <div class="field" >
        <%= f.label :email %><br />
        <%= f.email_field :email, autofocus: true %>
     </div>

     <div class="field">
        <%= f.label :password %>
        <% if @minimum_password_length %>
          <em>(<%= @minimum_password_length %> chara min)</em>
        <% end %><br />
        <%= f.password_field :password, autocomplete: "off" %>
     </div>

     <div class="field">
        <%= f.label :password_confirmation %><br />
        <%= f.password_field :password_confirmation, autocomplete: "off" %>
     </div>

     <div class="field" >
        <%= f.label :designation %><br />
        <%= f.text_field :designation, autofocus: true %>
     </div>

     <div class="actions">
        <%= f.submit "Sign up" %>
     </div>
    <%= render "users/shared/links" %> 
 </div>
```

Now added this to ApplicationController.rb

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
     before_action :configure_permitted_parameters, if: :devise_controller?

 protected

   def configure_permitted_parameters
      devise_parameter_sanitizer.permit(:sign_up, keys: [:designation])
   end
end
```